# Wordress admin page is fetching error You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Tags: plugins, pages, admin, permissions, user-access

Wordress admin page is fetching error You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. Mysite url is https://www.artvault.co.in but its admin panel url - https://www.artvault.co.in/wp-admin is rendering an unknown error You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. Where I thoroughly checked the $table prefix : wp_ is same in databse usermeta tables. I tried to deactivate the all plugins nothing is helpful. Anyone can tell something what happeed.?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your WP database in phpmyadmin. Here in option table locate WordPress Site (URL) and WordPress Address (URL) row. change these two field. https://www.artvault.co.in in WordPress Site (URL) and https://www.artvault.co.in/wp-admin in WordPress Address (URL)